# How to Write XML in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

```
<Account nr="401" name="Wasser/Abwasser" income="0.00" expenditure="1,310.74" saldo="-1,310.74" resultText="Es wurden ausgegeben">
    <Accounting date="15.02." refNr="....." description="I/2013"  income="" expenditure="1,310.74" vat="10%" pretax="131.07"/>
  </Account>
```

I can use XmlTextWriter but dont know how to continue with nr,name.....

```
myXmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Account");.....
myXmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Accounting",......
```

thx

Comment: Are you ought to use XmlTextWriter? LINQ to XML is much simpler to use

Comment: Do you particularly *want* to use XmlTextWriter? Can you use LINQ to XML instead? (It'll make your life much easier...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to issue a `WriteAttributeString`:

```
myXmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString(null, "nr", null, "401");
myXmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

and do that right after the `WriteStartElement`.

You could probably use this overload too:

```
myXmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("nr", "401");
```

and of course replicate that for all other attributes. And it would work the same for the child node as well.

Comment: i didn't know about WriteAttributeString..i'll try your approach too..thx

Comment: yes it works...thx to everyone..sorry i can accept only one answer as correct

Answer (score 7):

Try using `XElement` end `XAttribute` classes. They are part of LINQ to XML and they make work with XML much easier.

```
var xml = new XElement("Account",
              new XAttribute("nr", 401),
              new XAttribute("name", "Wasser/Abwasser"),
              new XElement("Accounting",
                  new XAttribute("date", "15.02."),
                  new XAttribute("refNr", "...")));
```

That one returns on `.ToString()`:

```
<Account nr="401" name="Wasser/Abwasser">
  <Accounting date="15.02." refNr="..." />
</Account>
```

Fill the rest of attributes following the pattern and you'll have what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ to XML you can do it very simply:

```
var document = new XDocument( 
                   new XElement("Account",
                       new XAttribute("nr", 401),
                          ...));
document.WriteTo(myXmlTextWriter);
```